# how to configure prometheus for service discovery with application pods running in different namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

configure prometheus for service discovery with application pods running in different namespaces

```
/*With single namespace it's fine to do like this:

  prometheus.io/path: "/metrics" //endpoint
  prometheus.io/port: "8001" // port
  prometheus.io/scrape: "true" //To scrape

but with different namespace not able to configure */
```